# Firefox/chrome is not displying uploaded image but IE6 is displaying in php why so

Tags: php

HI Everybody

I am uploading an user image while he/she sign up and then in his/her home page i have given a link if he/she want to show his/her uploaded image.There is no problem ..

But when i try to see this image through firefox/chrome my image is not displaying only a tiny icon is displaying there.Image is jpeg type

But when i am trying to display this image through IE6 it is displyed no problem there..

May i know why this..

```
<?php
session_start();



    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$con)
    {
    die('Could Not Connect:'.mysql_error());
    } 

    mysql_select_db("tcs",$con);

    $usr=$_SESSION['employee']['username'];
    $query="select * from employee where Username='$usr'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($query,$con);


    if ($result) 
    {

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $addr=$row['File Name'];

    }           
?>

<html>
<body>

<img src="<?php echo $addr ; ?>" width="200" height="150" alt="Deepak Narwal">


</body>
</html>
```

This is how i am displaying the uplaoded image which one use upload at the time of sign-up i am storing it into hard disk in one folder under htdocs and full address of this i am storing into database under File Name

Comment: Can you give us the link to the image ? Maybe it's a corrupted (invalid) one, and the library used by IE is more permissive than the one used by FF/Chrome ?

Comment: it is only one application which i am creating.Image is my photo and it is stored in valid folder

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. MIME settings?

IE-HTML?  (IE6 is tring to fix some problems such as:

```
<p<img
```

(code from some real site)).

It would be worth to know what the icon is. or code.

PS. Problem is rather on client-side or at least on 'static' side rather then in PHP.